# Datatable server-side using Eloquent with laravel

Tags: laravel, package, datatables, eloquent, server-side

im using bllim-datatables package for laravel server side and i don't understand how to do if, for example, i want to display only posts from user = 2 with eloquent.

```
$posts = Post::select(array('posts.id','posts.name','posts.created_at','posts.status'));

return Datatables::of($posts)
->filter_column('id', 'where', 'User.id', '=', '2')
->make();
```

I know this is not gonna work but can someone explain to me the correct way, please ?

Comment: can you not just use like Post::where('id',2)->select(array());

Comment: no you have to use select(), check this https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package

Comment: Post::select(array())->where('User.id', '=', '2'); doesnt works!

Comment: Can you please show me your database table field names and their relations ? You can simply use `$posts = DB::table('posts')->where('user_id' , 2)->get();` Then you can use a foreach loop to grab the post , cause you can now know $posts will deliver the posts whose user_id = 2 . Thank you.

Comment: solution:  Posts::select()->where('user_id',2);

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question too. But it must use filter_column

Comment: why don't just use `syamsoulcc/laravel-datatable-ssp`?? you can refer this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527294/datatable-server-side-php-class-for-laravel/55275944#55275944