# Datatable server side php class for laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables

I want my datatables to process the data on the server side, I am referencing this example.

[Server Side Example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

However, the server side php class "ssp.class.php" given in this example uses core php with raw sql, I can not use it directly for laravel projects. Does anyone has reference to laravel way doing datatables. I don't want to use any packages at the moment though.

Comment: Read the Laravel documentation on [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) and/or the [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries)

Comment: Why can't you use it in laravel, I have used in Datatables and Flexigrid ( https://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/ ) in many of my projects in laravel . I recommend you to use eloquent / query builder according to your usage as @lukasgeiter suggests

Comment: @lukasgeiter I know how to use laravel Eloquent ORM, the problem I am facing is how does the datatables communicates with the server side script? Once I have a better understanding of protocols then there wouldn't be any problem translating it.

Comment: Have you looked at a laravel datatables package. There are a few around to handle the server side processing

Comment: Have you found a way to make it work? It's been already more than a year...

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED 14 Oct 2023**

You can use `syamsoul/laravel-datatable-ssp` package..

[Link here][2]

1. Open CLI and enter your app directory
2. Run this command `composer require syamsoul/laravel-datatable-ssp`
3. In your controller, you can follow the code below:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Testing;

   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use SoulDoit\DataTable\SSP;
   use App\Models\User;

   class DatatableJsController extends Controller
   {
       public function index(SSP $ssp)
       {
           $ssp->setColumns([
               ['label' => 'ID',         'db' => 'id',         'formatter' => function ($value) {
                   return str_pad($value, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
               }],
               ['label' => 'Email',      'db' => 'email'       ],
               ['label' => 'Username',   'db' => 'username'    ],
               ['label' => 'Created At', 'db' => 'created_at'  ],
           ]);

           $ssp->setQuery(function ($selected_columns) {
               return User::select($selected_columns);
           });

           return $ssp->response()->json();
       }
   }
   ```

This is working perfectly on `Laravel 9` and above.

For more info, you can refer to the documentation site: https://info.souldoit.com/projects/laravel-datatable-ssp
.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function list()
{        
    $dt_obj = $this->data();
   
    return view('userslist', [
        'dt_info'       => $dt_obj->getInfo(),
    ]);
}
public function get($id=null)
{
    // echo "dd";die;
    $dt_obj = $this->data();        
    return response()->json($dt_obj->getDtArr());
}
public function data(){
    $dt = [
        ['label'=>'ID',         'db'=>'id',            'dt'=>0],
        ['label'=>'first_name',      'db'=>'first_name',         'dt'=>1],
        ['label'=>'last_name',   'db'=>'last_name',         'dt'=>2],
        ['label'=>'Created At', 'db'=>'created_at',    'dt'=>3],
       
    ];
  return (new SSP('\App\Models\User', $dt));

}
```

ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datatable_1').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: 'http://localhost/pdf-generate/public/get',
            columns: {!!json_encode($dt_info['labels'])!!},
            order: {!!json_encode($dt_info['order'])!!},
        });
        // console.log('dd',columns);   
    });
```

route call

Route::get('data1', [DataTable::class, 'list']);

Route::get('get', [DataTable::class, 'get']);

Comment: It's working in laravel 8 also.

Comment: I fetch 20000 and more record within a second . its work faster

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).